# Quotient of finitely approximable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question about finitely approximable groups. The fact is that quotient of finitely approximable group can be not f.approximable. Can you give me any example. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, thus is not finitely approximable. So I want to find finitely approximable group with the quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free groups are finitely approximable (a.k.a. residually finite), and every group $G$ is a quotient of the free group on $|G|$ letters.